# Picasso takes a long time to download the images in my app

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, picasso

Hi I'm doing an application with several ImageButtton and for not loading both the application I'm using Picasso and Xampp to fill them.
What happens scheme takes a long time to put the images in their corresponding ImageButton. Does anyone know why?

Here I attach my code.

```
 public class SedeValencia extends Fragment {

private ImageButton ima1;
private ImageButton ima2;
private ImageButton ima3;
private ImageButton ima4;
private ImageButton ima5;
private ImageButton ima6;
private View v;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment

v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sede_valencia,container,false);

ima1 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc1);
ima2 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc2);
ima3 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc3);
ima4 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc4);
ima5 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc5);
ima6 = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imgbtnvlc6);



Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/vlc/pasedi.jpg")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima1);

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/vlc/vidaiglevlc.jpg")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima2);

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/vlc/reunionesvlc.jpg")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima3);

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp//vlc/ubivlc.jpg")
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima4);

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load("http://192.168.2.113/imagenesapp/redesvlc.jpg" )
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_cloud_queue_black_24px).into(ima5);


return v;

}
```

Comment: Glide is better for your case it's more faster.

Comment: How did Glide work and what is it?